# Octave. DC after apply high pass filter

Tags: filter, octave, highpass-filter

I'm writting an script to apply a high pass filter to an ECG signal with Octave, using the remez function. The code, basically, is like this:

```
fs = 500;    % sampling frequency
nyq = fs/2;  % Nyquist frecuency
% remez parameters
N = 256;     % filter order
f1 = 0.2;    % begin of transition band in hz
f2 = 4;      % end of transition band in hz
F = [0 f1/nyq f2/nyq 1];
A = [0 0 1 1];
hc1 = remez(N,F,A);
xf1 = filter(hc1,1,data_vector);
```

If I plot the results, I obtain:

[Plot of the filtered vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVMzM.png)

So, my problem is that seems the high pass filter is working well, but the signal has an offset. I expected to see the signal centered on zero (without that dc offset).

What could be the reason of that offset?

PD: in that plot I didn't include the first N+2 values, because they are the initializing values of the filter.

Thank you.